# How can I handle "datetime" in mongoDB with php?

Tags: php, datetime, mongodb

Is there a way to store datetime? So that I can calculate time difference between two datetimes and query with range of datetime.

Also I want to indicate an exact time.    ex) 12:00:00 01-Jan-2001

Should I store both unix-stamp time and datetime string with timezone or other better ways to handle this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the [MongoDate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) class for storing dates in MongoDB.

From the manual...

> MongoDB stores dates as milliseconds past the epoch. This means that dates do not contain timezone information. Timezones must be stored in a separate field if needed

You can convert these to `DateTime` objects by retrieving the `sec` property and using it in [`DateTime::setTimestamp()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php). Also see [`DateTime::setTimezone()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

Comment: Look at this post: http://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html. It explains why you need to store the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application that has to deal with different timezones I will transform all dates to an application timezone before saving them to the db. This way you can do proper calculations. If you need to go back to the original timezone during the application, then save also the name of the original timezone and you will be able to recalculate back.